# Автоматизация ввода данных из Excel в форму на сайте

Tags: excel

Нужно автоматизировать рутинную работу. Есть клиентская часть базы данных работающая через сеть, куда ежедневно нужно вводить массив данных из Excel, около 100 типовых заявок состоящих из 5 полей - *номер заявки*, *дата приема*, *срок исполнения*, *кто исполнил* и т.д. Сейчас исполняется вручную, огромные трудозатраты.
Каким образом лучше решить? Скрипт? Расширение для браузера? Макрорекордер?

Comment: Т.е. вам надо из Еxcel вводить данные в базу, используя веб-интерфейс?

Comment: Верно, именно так

Comment: как вариант, надо посмотреть какой запрос уходит на сервер. Собственно скриптом его и сгенрерировать, заполним необходимые поля запроса